# Why isn't Javac running on multiple cores?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, compiler-construction, javac, multicore

It can look quite a generic question, but what is the very technical reason for javac not to compile concurrently ? I read that the eclipse compiler is parallel, so why not javac ?

Comment: The "very technical" reason is that Sun / Oracle did not not designed / implemented the `javac` compiler that way.  I imagine they have more important things to do ... in terms of delivering product that will earn money for Oracle.

Comment: What about open jdk then ?

Comment: What about it?  The same reasoning applies there.  In reality, OpenJDK is 99.x% the same codebase as the Oracle badged JDK release ... and developed by the same team of people.

Comment: I mean there is now more room to get motivated to do just a better compiler.

Comment: It is the same people (Oracle employees), with the same (Oracle) managers setting their priorities.  And it is your just your opinon that it would make the compiler better.  On the other hand, if you have (I am guessing) 12 man months to spend overhauling the java compiler **for free** (and you have compiler-writing skills), I suggest that you volunteer :-)

Comment: If others are interested, actually I am ;) I believe the gain in productivity would be huge. Or will another language do it before (Kotlin ?)

Comment: If you are interested in doing the work, put your hand up.  If you are interested in someone else volunteering .... good luck with that :-)

Comment: You will never be able to compile faster than you can read source code or write class files. So before you start trying to optimize the processing that happens in-between, you should check the size of its fraction on the entire process. It might be discouraging…

Comment: What about this answer, where it is demonstrated that javac does run on multiple cores even for single files?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553913/1262865

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unusual for compilers to actually work in parallel and I can't find any sources that say that Eclipse's Java compiler is an exception.

What eclipse does have the ability to do, is to compile multiple files in parallel at the same time. This is unrelated to the fact that Eclipse comes with its own Java-compiler. If it did use javac it could just run multiple instances of `javac` in parallel - there's no problem with that. And in fact that's exactly what build tools such as maven do when you run a build with multiple threads.

Comment: Do you mean compiling in parallel in different modules ? Gradle does that too, but here I am really talking about compiling 1 module in parallel.

Comment: @Snicolas I meant compiling different files in parallel. It's perfectly possible to compile different files from the same module in parallel (or to do this in Java versions that don't have modules). What isn't possible is to compile a single file in parallel.

Answer (score -2):

I think it makes **javac** program simple, if it's internal parallel, then many race condition has to be handled, which complicate the thing. To utilize multi-core, you can create multiple javac process to reach the same goal, seems that makefile and gcc works like this way.

> "Keep it simple and stupid"