# Is it possible to compile a large Java module in parallel?

Tags: java, performance, compilation, javac

I know that multiple modules can be compiled using multiple threads where each thread compiles a single module but what if I have a single large module? Does Javac or the Eclipse Java Compiler support compiling single modules in parallel (using many threads)? Or is there any other Java compiler which supports it?

**Update**: I created a Java source file with ~50k simple methods (just for the purpose of this test) such as:

```java
    static int add1(int a, int b, int c) {
        return 2 * a + 55 * b - c;
    }

   static int add2(int a, int b, int c) {
        return 2 * a + 55 * b - c;
    }

   static int add3(int a, int b, int c) {
        return 2 * a + 55 * b - c;
    }
```

These methods do not depend on each other so compilation could be done in parallel (at least in theory). Compiling this file with `Javac` on my 12 core + HT machine lead to an average 20% CPU usage with a really short spike of up to 50%. This leads me to believe that although there is some parralelization done inside `Javac`, it is really minor.

The **interesting** thing is that if I create 2, 3 or 4 classes with the same number of methods and compile them at the same time with a single `Javac` process, I cannot get a higher CPU usage. The compilation takes exactly 2x, 3x, 4x longer which shows that Javac doesn't compile these totally unrelated classes in parallel. But if I start separate Javac processes to compile these files separately, the CPU jumps to almost 100% when 4 files(=`Javac` processes) are used and the compilation time is just 5-10% higher than compiling a single file (compared to this, a single `Javac` process compiling all these 4 files, the compilation takes 400% longer).

So my opinion is that `Javac` does compile files using multiple threads but it is kind of limited to ~4 threads, it cannot fully utilize a 12 cores machine. Also to me it seems that `Javac` compiles **multiple** files in serial, it only uses cores/threads to compile a single file in parallel(I believe that when a single file is compiled, some parts can be done in parallel and this is what Javac does, **but what about compiling multiple files in parallel?** If I have 100 files which are independent I should be able to see my CPU jump to 100% which is not the case.)

Comment: `maven` supports parallel build https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

Comment: @Liquidpie as far as I know it only works if the project has multiple modules

Comment: There are only two compilers tracking the latest versions of java in wide use, which would be important to me.  The openjdk one and the eclipse one.  I would have a very close look at the eclipse one to see what it can do.

Comment: You have a class with 50000 methods?

Comment: @akuzminykh I don't. I just created it for the purpose of this test.

Comment: You might want to check out the following post because it has details that could be interesting: [why parallel execution on java compile take linear growth in time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30684904/12323248)

Comment: @akuzminykh thanks, will take a look

Comment: How would the compiler know that two Java files are independent of each other without first compiling them? (Remember, if class A depends on class B, and both classes are currently in source form, while compiling A the compiler will see that there is a B.java file without a B.class file, and compile B.java.)

Comment: @k314159 this is a fair point, but I still think that `Javac` could do better, like it could compile files in multiple steps and during a very fast first step it could already know that the file is independent.

Comment: now think about how many users are _really_ affected by this? and take it into a different perspective. 20 years in and `HashSet` _still_ uses a `HashMap` under the hood (I can make more examples like this). The idea is that such optimizations might not ever be a priority to the JDK team. Unless a VERY brave and smart enthusiast wants to help with a PR (which will never happen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible to build Java code in parallel.

The Java compiler (`javac`) itself doesn't do this, but both Maven and Ant (and some versions of Make) can run multiple `javac` instances in parallel.

Furthermore, the Eclipse Java compiler is multi-threaded and you can tell Maven to use it instead of `javac`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3727542/139985

---

I note that your example involves compiling a single class with a huge number of methods.  Parallel compiler instances won't help with that.  The Eclipse compiler *might* help depending on how it is implemented.

However, I put it to you that that is an unrealistic example.  People don't write code like that in real life<sup>1</sup>, and code generators can (and should) be written to not emit source code like that.

<sup>1 - Their co-workers will rebel ...</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`javac` runs always single-threaded. There is a case for improving javac performance [JDK-4229449 : RFE: Please multithread javac for better performance](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4229449) however Oracle does not intend to change the compilation architecture.

Comment: You're right. This was submitted in 1999!! and it was marked as `Closed`, `Resolution: Won't Fix`. What a pity!

Comment: The way of mind is one. I also think multithreaded compilation can be useful

Comment: `This was submitted in 1999!! and it was marked as Closed`. Yes, but only because the issue was too specific how performance should be improved. From the comments: `Yes, the compiler should be faster. [...] But this RFE is a bit too specific in suggesting how we do that.`. I think Java compiler developers do consider compilation performance in general.

Comment: There is a newer issue here with status `closed/delivered` [JEP 139](https://openjdk.org/jeps/139)